# Expected identifier for unnamed pointer return value

Tags: go

`gofmt` gives an "expected identifier" warning about this function signature at this point:

```
func foo() (*int, y int) {}
            ^
```

However, it does not complain about this signature:

```
func foo() (int, y int) {}
```

How can I name one return value without having `gofmt` complain about the unnamed pointer return value?

Comment: You can't. Your return values can be named, or unnamed, but you can't have a mix of both - it's syntactically invalid and also wouldn't make any sense to do in practice.

Comment: What @Adrian said, also Go doesn't complain about your second case because `int` is a valid identifier name, `*` is not. That is, inside the function `foo` the identifier `int` would be the return variable not the type (https://play.golang.org/p/6AkxRIE9_FC).